# What is the difference between quote data, trade data and pricing data in stock market?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, quotes

I am new to stock market. I never found any clear response on internet for this query. Few define quote data as the last traded value, few define it as the bid & ask value. I also wonder OHLC values lie in which category. 
Could you please help me understand this concept with examples?

Answer (score 2):

A current quote has the bid and ask price, the price of the last trade, the size of the market at the bid and the ask, and net change.

A Summary Quotes provides a more comprehensive view.  It usually contains:

> Symbol
>
> Name
>
> Open
>
> Bid
>
> Ask
>
> Previous Close
>
> Last Trade
>
> Volume (during regular hours)
>
> Today's Low
>
> Today's High

It may also include:

> Week's Low
>
> Week's High
>
> 52 Week High
>
> 52 Week Low
>
> EPS
>
> PE Ratio
>
> Shares Outstanding
>
> Market Cap
>
> Dividend
>
> Ex-Div Date
>
> Yield